# Xampp php permission denied when trying to post images using imgur api?

Tags: php, xampp, imgur

The error I get:

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.imgur.com/3/image): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Permission Denied in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sn0\classes\Image.php on line 22
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sn0\classes\Image.php on line 25
>
> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\sn0\classes\Image.php on line 25

Here's my Image.php file:

```
<?php
class Image {

        public static function uploadImage($formname, $query, $params) {
                $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES[$formname]['tmp_name']));

                $options = array('http'=>array(
                        'method'=>"POST",
                        'header'=>"Authorization: Bearer ###\n".
                        "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                        'content'=>$image
                ));

                $context = stream_context_create($options);

                $imgurURL = "https://api.imgur.com/3/image";

                if ($_FILES[$formname]['size'] > 10240000) {
                        die('Image too big, must be 10MB or less!');
                }

                $response = file_get_contents($imgurURL, false, $context);
                $response = json_decode($response);

                $preparams = array($formname=>$response->data->link);

                $params = $preparams + $params;

                DB::query($query, $params);

        }

}
?>
```

Comment: Imgur responds with `Authentication required`, i.e. you need to provide some form of authentication to use the API endpoint. Imgur has a pretty nice API documentation at https://apidocs.imgur.com – you should probably give that a read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You making bad request.

At the beginning you need to generate your Client ID (more info @ https://api.imgur.com/#registerapp)

To do this go to https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient
and
Select **Anonymous usage without user authorization option** as Authorization Type.

Use Authorization: **Client-ID** not Bearer, you can keep file_get_contents (so - then you need change only authorization header) but CURL will be better for this.

Example with CURL:

```
<?php
class Image
{
    public static function uploadImage($formname, $query, $params)
    {
        $client_id = 'YOUR CLIENT ID';
        $image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES[$formname]['tmp_name']));
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json',
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Authorization: Client-ID ' . $client_id
            ) ,
            CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                'image' => $image
            )
        ));
        $out = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        $response = json_decode($out);
        $preparams = array(
            $formname => $response->data->link
        );
        $params = $preparams + $params;
        DB::query($query, $params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives error  Notice: Undefined variable: client_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\sn0\classes\Image.php on line 12

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$link in C:\xampp\htdocs\sn0\classes\Image.php on line 24

Comment: Ahh.. sorry i missed $client_id varriable - replace 'YOUR CLIENT ID' with yours

Comment: Second error remains  Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$link in C:\xampp\htdocs\sn0\classes\Image.php on line 25

Comment: Can you paste me result of var_dump($out); ? you can add it after $out = curl_exec($curl);

Comment: string(115) "{"data":{"error":"Malformed auth header","request":"\/3\/image.json","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":403}"

Comment: Yes I did. 9a207d3f25eb29b

Comment: For me it's working - i have tested on my server. I have uploaded with your ClientID

https://i.imgur.com/n7M6ZbX.jpg

Comment: I used this code - only an external image, but it does not make a difference

https://pastebin.com/Xrp814V5

Answer (score 0):

`file_get_contents()` is used for GET requests. You need to use [CURL](https://davidwalsh.name/curl-post) in PHP in order to make a POST request from a server to another.